# How to use nasm to generate a dynamic linked exe on windows?

Tags: windows, linker, nasm, ld, dynamic-linking

Basically I know we can use this to create a static linked exe on windows 32 bit:

```
nasm -fwin32 test.s
cl.exe test.obj /link libcmt.lib
```

But how to create a dynamic-linked exe from the obj file nasm generated?

Comment: I haven't done this, but you can try replacing libcmt with msvcrt.

Comment: @MikeC Yes, it works! Actually I have tired msvcrt.dll, which says "can not find mscvrt"..

Comment: The .LIB is named "msvcrt"; the DLL is named according to the version of Visual C in use -- e.g. msvcrt90.dll