# How to assemble and link .asm files to a Win32 executable?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, linker, nasm

I have *NASM* and *Dev-Cpp* installed on my system. *Dev-cpp* comes with the *LD* (GNU Linker). I am new to assembly code and the processes to create a 32-bit Windows executable from an assembler file. I tried using this:

```
nasm -f win32 ass.asm
nasm -o ass ass.o
```

I had no success using these commands to create an executable. What is the proper way to assemble (with *NASM*) and link to generate an executable that will run on 32-bit Windows?

Comment: nasm is an assembler, it produces object files (or flat binaries but that's not applicable). You need to link the object using a linker.

Comment: nasm -f win32 outputs an object file, not a Win32 executable. You need a linker. If you don't have the GNU Binutils tools(which has the _LD_ linker) on your system (or Microsoft linker) I recommend downloading [GoLink](http://www.godevtool.com/) and then install it somewhere on your path. Then look at this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12575061/3857942)

Comment: Upvoting because it's not that bad a question.  It's well asked, easy to understand what the OP needs, and easy to answer.  It's very trivial, but it's not uncommon for something to be mysterious until you know how things work, and then it's trivial.  I'm surprised nobody's found a duplicate for it.  Most of the questions I found while searching have an answer to this as part of the question.  This one is nice and short: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010335/how-to-use-nasm-to-generate-a-dynamic-linked-exe-on-windows.  Oh, Michael's comment did link to a good Q&A.  dup-voted.

Comment: @Lesta: As a rookie, you're going to want to take a look at the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  You'll need a debugger while learning asm.  If you find a tutorial that's really helpful, but not mentioned in the wiki, leave a suggested edit for the wiki.  (Or reply to this comment and I'll add it.)

Comment: Thanks for the help Jesta, Michael and Peter. Those links really rock.

Comment: My comment about dev-cpp is based upon a comment that no longer exists, but I have updated the question. I've also voted to reopen it. Even if it becomes marked as a duplicate, it may still help someone else down the line while searching for a similar question.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I don't know if it's the OP or @MichaelPetch's edit, but this question is just fine.  No clue why it was closed.

Comment: I did vote to reopen.  We'll see.

Comment: Thanks for the vote. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

One of your comments that doesn't seem to exist anymore did mention that you had *Dev-Cpp* on installed on your Windows. If you have the *Dev-Cpp* MinGW bin directory on your path, then the GNU Linker *LD* is available to you.

I don't know if you are using a 32-bit or 64 GCC with *Dev-Cpp*, but this should work for both to generate a 32-bit executable:

```
nasm -f win32 ass.asm -o ass.obj
ld -mi386pe -o ass.exe ass.obj
```

That will tell NASM to generate a 32-bit Win32 object, and *LD* will link the object to an i386pe 32-bit Windows executable.

Alternatively you could download the the [GoLink linker](http://www.godevtool.com/). Once you extract it onto your path you could do something like:

```
nasm -f win32 ass.asm -o ass.obj
GoLink.exe  /console ass.obj kernel32.dll user32.dll gdi32.dll
```

You may have to specify your code entry point (label) with something like:

```
GoLink.exe  /console /entry _start ass.obj kernel32.dll user32.dll gdi32.dll
```

Where `_start` could be the label where you expect your program to start. You don't need any of the DLL's listed if you aren't calling any of the Win32 API.

If you aren't creating a console application then you can leave off `/console`

Comment: linked it probably well with devs linker, but throws a warning: "ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _mainCRTStartup; defaulting to 00401000" .What could I have missed???

Comment: @LestaCrenay Odd, are you using _gcc_ at all by any chance? What commands are you now using to compile/assemble and link?

Comment: @LestaCrenay : It sounds like you are trying to link with the Microsoft C runtime library.

Comment: The warning is gone. Managed to erase it but the program crashes. It shows the hello.exe has stopped working popup window when run ..The linking command is: ld -e _WinMain@16 hello.o -o hello.exe. Atleast, it doesn't show any warning. What could be the flaw? And Thanks for the edit @Michael Petch. The question sounds cooler.